# SED substitution for variable

Tags: sed, substitution

I have a file named check.txt which has the below contents:

```
$ cat check.txt
~/bin/tibemsadmin -server $URL-user $USER -password $PASWRD
$
```

I have a main script where the values of $URL, $USER, $PASWRD are obtained from the main script.  I want to use the SED utility to replace the $URL, $USER, $PASWRD to the actual values in the check.txt.

I am trying like this but it fails.

```
emsurl=tcp://myserver:3243
emsuser=test
emspasswd=new
sed s/$URL/${emsurl}/g check.txt >> check_new.txt
sed s/$USER/${emsuser}/g check.txt_new.txt >> check_new_1.txt
sed s/PASWRD/${emspasswd}/g check_new_1.txt >> final.txt
```

My final.txt output is desired as below:

```
~/bin/tibemsadmin -server tcp://myserver:3243 -user test -password new
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 3):

You have to be rather careful with your use of quotes.  You also need to learn how to do multiple operations in a single pass, and/or how to use pipes.

```
emsurl=tcp://myserver:3243
emsuser=test
emspasswd=new
sed -e "s%\$URL%${emsurl}%g" \
    -e "s%\$USER%${emsuser}%g" \
    -e "s%\$PASWRD%${emspasswd}%g" check.txt >final.txt
```

Your problem is that the shell expanded the '$URL' in your command line (probably to nothing), meaning that `sed` got to see something other than what you intended.  By escaping the `$` with the `\`, `sed` gets to see what you intended.

Note that I initially used `/` as the separator in the substitute operations; however, as [DarkDust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400056/darkdust) rightly points out, that won't work since there are slashes in the URLs.  My normal fallback character is `%` - as now shown - but that can appear in some URLs and might not be appropriate.  I'd probably use a control character, such as control-A, if I needed to worry about that - or I'd use Perl which would be able to play without getting confused.

You can also combine the three separate `-e` expressions into one with semi-colons replacing them.  However, I prefer the clarity of the three operations clearly separated.

Comment: You need to choose a different delimiter, `/` is used in the replacement text.

Comment: Dear Jon,DarkDust and Steve. Thanks a lot for your help. I have now understood where I am going wrong. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a slightly different approach by modifying your main script as follows :-

```
export URL="tcp://myserver:3243"
export USER=test
export PASWRD=new
. ./check.txt
```

This sets up the variables and then runs check.txt within the context of your main script

Comment: +1 for thinking out of the box - but not helping him learn how to use `sed` properly.  He'd need to upgrade the script to deal with unset variables, too (`${URL:?}` as a basic minimum).  Also, there's no need to use `. ./check.txt`; it can be run simply as `./check.txt` or `sh check.txt` if the variables are exported.  If the variables were merely set, then the `.` command would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Although you don't say what's failing I guess I see the problems.

I suggest you do this:

```
sed "s|\$URL|${emsurl}|g"
```

That is, the first `$` needs to be escaped because you want it literally. Then, instead of `/` I suggest you use `|` (pipe) as delimiter since it's not used in your strings. Finally, use `"` to ensure the content is interpreted as string by the shell.

You can then pipe everything together to not need any temporary files:

```
sed "s|\$URL|${emsurl}|g" | sed "s|\$USER|${emsuser}|g" | sed "s|\$PASSWRD|${emspasswd}|g"
```

Comment: You can do it all in one sed command by using repeated '-e' options, which is considerably more efficient.  But using pipes is much preferable to using explicit intermediate files (which were not cleaned up in the original).

Answer (score 0):

Variable substitution should be outside sed expression and '$' should be escaped; in your case something like this:

```
sed -e 's/\$URL/'$emsurl'/g' -e 's/\$USER/'$emsuser'/g' -e 's/\$PASSWORD/'$emaspasswd'/g'
```

Anyway in your place I would avoid using $ to match placeholders in a template file, because it's causing confusion with BASH variables, use a different pattern instead (for instance @URL@).